# No Database Connection: MariaDB Won't Start

Tags: mariadb

When I run the command `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart`, my Apache server starts but MariaDB does not. Below are the logs from `journalctl -xe`.

```
Aug 16 16:29:54 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: ## 2022-08-16 16:29:54+00:00 ## INFO ## Starting services...
Aug 16 16:29:55 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: 2022-08-16T16:29:55.550Z - info: Saving configuration info to disk
Aug 16 16:29:55 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: 2022-08-16T16:29:55.915Z - info: Performing service start operation for php
Aug 16 16:29:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: php 16:29:56.22 INFO  ==> php-fpm is already running
Aug 16 16:29:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: 2022-08-16T16:29:56.225Z - info: Performing service start operation for apache
Aug 16 16:29:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: apache 16:29:56.50 INFO  ==> apache is already running
Aug 16 16:29:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: 2022-08-16T16:29:56.503Z - info: Skipping service start operation for varnish
Aug 16 16:29:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: 2022-08-16T16:29:56.503Z - info: Performing service start operation for mariadb
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: mariadb 16:30:56.82 ERROR ==> mariadb did not start
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: 2022-08-16T16:30:56.831Z - error: Unable to perform start operation Export start for mariadb failed with exit code 1
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: ## 2022-08-16 16:30:56+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/010_bitnami_agent_extra...
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: ## 2022-08-16 16:30:56+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/020_bitnami_agent...
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: ## 2022-08-16 16:30:56+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/030_update_welcome_file...
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: ## 2022-08-16 16:30:56+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/040_bitnami_credentials_file...
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: ## 2022-08-16 16:30:56+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/050_clean_metadata...
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 sudo[7255]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 systemd[1]: bitnami.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit bitnami.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
```

When I try restarting just MariaDB (`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart mariadb`), the command hangs for about 1 minute and then I get the following (unhelpful) error:

`Failed to restart mariadb: Failed to restart mariadb`

I'm not sure what else to do here.

Comment: What's your question exactly? How to find the MySQL log file? Something else?

Comment: How do I start the MariaDB so that it restores my DB connection?

Comment: You fix the problem that prevents it from starting in the first place. For that you find its error log, find the error message, and act accordingly.

Comment: Now that's a good question, to which you will [easily find the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+where+to+find+error+log).

Comment: cat /opt/bitnami/mariadb/logs/mysqld.log shows nothing. it's empty.

Comment: Also, logs haven't been updated since May 2022

Comment: Did you use your database since May 2022?  If not, then a simple re-install would be an option?